# Store search results GridView

Tags: asp.net, store

I have the following GridView:

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    gridlines="None"
    cellpadding="15"
    width="980px"   
    ItemStyle-backcolor="#ebecf0"
    AlternatingItemStyle-backcolor="#ebecf0" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    PageSize="4" 
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    datasourceid="SqlDataSource2"
    >
```

And this select command:

```
"SELECT * FROM [tbl_Project] INNER JOIN tbl_Cat      
ON tbl_Project.CatID = tbl_Cat.Cat_ID 
INNER JOIN tbl_Klant   
ON tbl_Project.KlantID = tbl_Klant.Klant_ID 
WHERE (([Titel] LIKE '%' + @Titel + '%') 
AND  ([CatID] = CASE WHEN @CatID = -1 THEN [CatID] ELSE @CatID END) 
AND ([Bedrijf] LIKE '%' + @Bedrijf + '%') 
AND ([Website] LIKE '%' + @Website + '%'))"
```

This allows the user to search records in the database. In the GridView1 I havea detail button:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="klant" runat="server"
    Text='<%#Eval("Bedrijf") %>'
    PostBackUrl='<%# "klant_wijzigen.aspx?Klant_ID="+Eval("Klant_ID").ToString()%>'>
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

this takes the user to a new page with the details of that certain subjec(based on ID)

**QUESTION**

But when the user clicks on "back" the seaarch results are cleared. How can I store those searched records and display them on PageLoad.

I have tried it trough cookies and Session but it dindt work.

**EDIT**

my sesion attempt:

```
Session("Test") = GridView1
GridView1 = Nothing

' Retrieve GridView from Session
GridView1 = DirectCast(Session("Test"), GridView)
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: by session is the best way but instead of storing the whole `GridView` into your session just store the values of the parameters that you are using into your `where clause` , when you will come back then just assign those parameters to your query again and bind your grid view again.

Comment: And how exactly do I do that, just instead of GridView the text-boxes.text? do you have a tutorial ( dont  realy like snippets )

Comment: i don't have tutorial but i did this same thing on my hand, if you are willing then i may give you little bit help.it will be very easy,Also mentioned `vb` into your question tag.

Comment: That would be very kind, if you could me a direction would be great ( I am not realy great with SQL )

Comment: hey see my updated answer, i tried my best to help you, If found any problem then ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try to use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx) event of `LinkButton` instead of `PostBackUrl`.

When you will click on `LinkButton` then on it's `OnClientClick` event do some steps.

1. Store the values of the parameters that you are passing in `Select Query` in `Session`.

   It may come from anywhere like from `Textbox's`,`Label's` etc etc.If it's come from controls then store in session like

   ```
   Session("Bedrijf") = Bedrijf.Text
   ```

   Here I am assuming that `Bedrijf` value comes from a `TextBox` of ID `Bedrijf.Text`. So I save that value into a `session`. Just store the others controls value as well.

   Note: only store those values that has been used into your select query.

   After storing all values into session. You just redirect it to the next page.
2. On page2 do what ever you want.
3. On `back button` click also set the `pagename` into your `session` variables.Right now you are on `page2.aspx` so set it's name in `session` like

   ```
   Session("prevpagename") = "Page2"
   ```
4. After hitting back button it will redirect to the same page like `page 2 to page 1`, now here on `page 1` `Page_Load` event bind your `grid view` again like

   ```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
         // Here firstly check the session variables for `pagename`
         If Session("prevpagename") = "Page2" Then
         // then directly assign the values of the parameters that you have store in session in select query.
         // After retrieving the values from the database filter by the parameters you have passed bind your `Grid View` again like
         gridview.DataSource = reader2
         gridview.DataBind()
         // Here reader2 is having the all return data that comes from your select query.You may save them on `DataTable`,`DataSet` as well and directly assign it to `DataSource` event of `GridView`.
         Else
         // another code.
         End If
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

You have to follow this type of scenario.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: Will that work even when .text = Null? They don have to fill in every field.

Comment: store every value in `session` but when you will assign those values to query then check for `Null` as well.

Comment: on point 3 you have to store the name of your page so that you may get that you may come to page1 from which page. so that you may apply condtion very well.

Comment: instead of getting the previous page name you may also use `Request.UrlReferrer` inbuild function of asp.net framework,must check

Comment: `reader2` it's a dummy variable used by me, you need to assign your variable in which you are storing your select query output.

Comment: Ahh oke, so in my case that would be Results. I stored the sessions in private sub results()

Comment: `private sub results() ` this is your method name, not variable name.what is the variable in which u r storing your select query data.like ex:- DataTable dt = "Select -----------"; you need to assign `dt` instead of `reader2` in example but in your case assign your variable,Are you new on asp.net.

Comment: Well i'm working with asp.net for for almost 2 months, so you could say i'm new indeed

Comment: 'So how do I put them in the td ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Cache` your tables. Like `Cache["SOURCE"] = YourSearchDataTable;` then call it by casting like this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Cache["SOURCE"];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Just a suggestion and alternative to session and cookies.

Comment: Do I put the cache on the search_click event?

Comment: Yes. You can put it `onClicked` event then you can retrieve it whenever you like.

Comment: Like this: `DataTable dt = (DataTable)Cache["SOURCE"];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

> Session("Test") = GridView1

I think this is bad, Instead save your select query in the session b4 redirection, also configure the detail page to redirect with somequery string value so that you know that you have to use select query from session.

Comment: I am not a hero with SQL, would be great i f you could point me into a right direction, or a good thread about it ( searched my ass off )

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by storing a session on selectedindex change like this:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Categorie") = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
End Sub

Protected Sub txtKlant_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Klant") = txtKlant.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub txtWebsite_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Website") = txtWebsite.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub txtTitel_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Titel") = txtTitel.Text
End Sub
```

and then calling it back on page_load liek this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Cookie()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then           
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("Categorie")
        txtKlant.Text = Session("Klant")
        txtWebsite.Text = Session("Website")
        txtTitel.Text = Session("Titel")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```